# On the quantity defecting in the Great Apostasy?

Tags: catholicism, prophecy, apostasy, catholic-bible, great-apostasy

On p. 230 of Fr. F. W. Faber's [*The Precious Blood*](https://ia802601.us.archive.org/21/items/a5807812fabe00uoft/a5807812fabe00uoft.pdf), we find the words:

> In the days of Antichrist, when two-thirds even of the faithful shall fall away from the Church.

Now, "a revolt" is spoken about in [2 Thess. 2:3](https://www.drbo.org/chapter/60002.htm), which, I surmise, is what Fr. Faber is referring to.

Can someone shed some light as to where the "two-thirds" figure may have come from? Can it be biblically inferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On the Quantity Defecting in the Great Apostasy?**

***”In the days of the Antichrist, when two-thirds even of the faithful shall have fall away from the Church.”***

I believe, that Fr. Faber numbers about the amount of two-thirds of the faithful leaving the Catholic Church (?) is being inferred from Zachariah 13:8-9.

> Some of the prophecies predict 2/3 and some predict ¾ of mankind will perish in the fire that comes down for three days and nights. Zachariah 13, verses 8 and 9 speak of a fire and one third being brought through the fire: “And there shall be in all the earth, saith the Lord, two parts in it shall be scattered, and shall perish: but the third part shall be left therein.  And I will bring the third part through the fire, and will refine them as silver is refined: and I will try them as gold is tried.” - [The Three Days of Darkness - Two Thirds to Three Quarters of Mankind will Perish. Fire from Heaven!](https://motherofgodlibrary.org/2023/10/25/the-three-days-of-darkness-two-thirds-to-three-quarters-of-mankind-will-perish-fire-will-fall-from-heaven/)

Prophecy is one of the hardest subject matters to completely understand, often only understood after the events have occurred.

Take for example that in the *Apocalypse*, or *Book of Revelation*, a third of mankind will perish.

> 14 Saying to the sixth angel, who had the trumpet: Loose the four angels, who are bound in the great river Euphrates.
> 15 And the four angels were loosed, who were prepared for an hour, and a day, and a month, and a year: for to kill the third part of men. [Revelation 9:14-15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%209&version=DRA)

Whatever the exact number of faithful who will abandon the Church, one thing is sure: **It will be significant!** This I believe is what Fr. Faber is inferring to here.

> 10 And then shall many be scandalized: and shall betray one another: and shall hate one another.
>
> 11 And many false prophets shall rise, and shall seduce many.
>
> 12 And because iniquity hath abounded, the charity of many shall grow cold.
>
> 13 But he that shall persevere to the end, he shall be saved.
>
> 14 And this gospel of the kingdom, shall be preached in the whole world, for a testimony to all nations, and then shall the consummation come. - [Matthew 24:10-14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2024%3A10-14&version=DRA)

This Great Apostasy refers to a significant falling away from the Catholic faith. This isn’t a rebellion against the government by unbelievers, this is a rebellion against Catholic belief and practice.

In the portion of 2 Thessalonians you cited above, St. Paul said that the Second Coming of the Lord Jesus Christ could not have already happened because:

- The rebellion must comes first!

> 3 Let no man deceive you by any means, for unless there come a revolt first, and the man of sin be revealed, the son of perdition. - [2 Thessalonians 2:3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Thessalonians%202%3A3&version=DRA)

- And the man of lawlessness must also appear!

> 8 And then that wicked one shall be revealed whom the Lord Jesus shall kill with the spirit of his mouth; and shall destroy with the brightness of his coming, him. - [2 Thessalonians 2:8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2+Thessalonians+2%3A8+&version=DRA)

How close we are to these events, no one can say yet, but I believe we are very close.

> For there shall be a time, when they will not endure sound doctrine; but, according to their own desires, they will heap to themselves teachers, having itching ears. [2 Timothy 4:3](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/2%20Timothy%204%3A3)

Comment: Many, many thanks for this answer.

Comment: Another thank you, Ken. It helped me understand better as well.